# finding 2-element subsets of $S_n$ which contain 2?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

For any positive integer $n$ let:
$$S_n = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$$
(a) for any integer $n \ge 2$, find the number of 2-element subsets of $S_n$ which contain 2.

(b) for any integer $n \ge 2$, find the number of subsets $A$ of $S_n$ with the property that $N(A) \in A$ where $N(A)$ is the cardinality of the set $A$. Answer must be in the form $2^N$ where $N$ is a simple expression involving $n$.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: The other element of the two-element set must be something other than $2$.  How many numbers other than $2$ belong to this set?

Comment: would it be $n-1$? so the number would be $\binom{n}{n-1}$?

Comment: Your comment starts out OK, but then you make it more complicated than it really is.

Comment: ok so the number of elements other than 2 would $n-1$ and the number of 2-element subsets which contain 2 would be $(n-1)!$ or am I still not getting it?

Comment: You're still making it too complicated.  Consider $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  The $2$-element subsets containing the number $2$ are these: $\{1,2\}$, $\{3,2\}$, $\{4,2\}$.  Do something similar when $n\ne4$.

Comment: would $\{2,1\}$ be another subset or is it considered the same as $\{1,2\}$?

Comment: They're the same set, since they have the same members.  Sets are not ordered.

Comment: Hint for b: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}=2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

(a) Picking a $2$-element subset of $S_n$ that contains $2$ is the same as picking a single element from $S_n\setminus\{2\}$.

(b) Let $f(n)$ be the number of subsets of $S_n$ with the property in question. There is $1$ $1$-element subset containing $1$. The answer to (a) is the number of $2$-element subsets containing $2$. Generalize (a) to find a simple expression for the number of $k$-element subsets containing $k$, for $k=3,\dots,n$. For instance, picking a $3$-element subset containing $3$ is the same as picking a $2$-element subset of $S_n\setminus\{3\}$. Now add those partial results and simplify; you’ll need only some basic facts about binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, choose $2$ in the beginning. Now you have to choose one more element from the set $(1,3,4,5,6..n)$.

That is you can choose one element from the set in $n-1 \choose 1$=$n-1$

Therefore, there are $n-1$ subsets which has two elements with $2$ has one of its elements in total.